# Including HTML form and related PHP in one file - with Javascript submit()

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, submit

I was wondering how it might be possible to do this... I already know how to include the form and PHP in one file:

```
<form method="post"> <!-- might also loop back to the same HTML file with action-->
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST["sent"])) {
        echo "<p>This string has been entered: " . $_POST["string"] . "</p><hr />";
    } 
?>
<p>Enter string:</p>
<p><input name="string" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit String" name="sent"></p>
</form>
```

But if I am using Javascript to use custom triggers I need to do it like this:

```
<form action="phpfile.php" name="myForm" method="post">
    <p>Enter Name: <input name="name" /></p>
</form>
<a href="javascript:document.myForm.submit();">Submit Name</a>
```

So there seems to be no way to reference any $_POST values I could use to check if they are already set... Is there a convenient solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after playing around a bit I found the answer: Yes, using the Javascript submit() method produces an $_POST array (if the form method is post), and all inputs can be referenced as usual via their name.

It's possible to use either isset($_POST["xxxxx"]) or $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] to check whether a chosen input is already set.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with request method is post, see example below:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    echo "<p>This string has been entered: " . $_POST["string"] . "</p><hr />";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful tipp, but does this help if I use Javascript's submit() function? I still see no way to access the data submitted with Javascript because it doesnt seem to produce any $_POST data... or does it?

Comment: you are just submitting from using javascript on click on anchor, which behaves same as submit button, the difference is just it can't post the value of anchor.

Comment: Well, and I can not access the $_POST data to check whether the data is already set...

Comment: if it's working well with submit button, then it should work with this solution too.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should change the link to
`<a href="#" onclick="document.myForm.submit(); return false">Submit Name</a>`
 it will submit whatever is entered in the form field which I would give a `type="text"` too.

If you need to also have 'Submit String' in the sent variable. add it as a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" value="Submit String" name="sent"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks, but does the JS submit that text as an element of the $_POST array? The Submit String is just a caption for the button, it's not really necessary.

Comment: Try and see - it should